# DeepExclude type for Typescript

Tags: typescript

I would like to have a recursive version of the `Exclude` type in Typescript.

Exclude removes a type from a type union. I would like a version that also removes the type from any nested objects and arrays.

For example

```
type O = DeepExclude<{foo: number | {bar: number}}, {bar: number}>;
```

Should be

```
type O = {
  foo: number;
}
```

Another example:

```
type O = MappedExclude<[number | {foo: {bar: number} | number}], {bar: number}>;
```

should be

```
type O = [number | {foo: number}]
```

Comment: Don't do this. No matter how sound *your* typing may be, at runtime this is still *Javascript* and your code should *always* be ready to accept object keys you didn't expect to be there. Don't count that you'll never see a number assigned to bar.

Comment: @JaredSmith can you elaborate on what you're warning about? I don't see the connection between the type function asked for here and any runtime issues; could you spell it out?

Comment: I mainly came here to find a way to exclude undefined or null, and that's well handled by the ts utility-types, DeepNonNullable and DeepRequired:
https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types#deepnonnullablet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would define `DeepExclude` like this:

```
type DeepExclude<T, U> =
  T extends U ? never :
  T extends object ? {
    [K in keyof T]: DeepExclude<T[K], U>
  } : T;
```

The first part is just like the [normal `Exclude<T, U>` definition](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/d3abd35428dd4e2435638146a0aa74a25bb89b7b/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1494)

```
// type Exclude<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;
```

which removes any pieces of the `T` union which are assignable to `U`.  Any remaining pieces of `T` which are primitives (not `object`) are returned as-is, also as if it were just `Exclude<T, U>`.  For any remaining pieces of `T` which are `object`s, though, we recurse down into its properties and do a `DeepExclude` on those.

Let's see if it works for your use cases:

```
type O = DeepExclude<{ foo: number | { bar: number } }, { bar: number }>;
/* type O = { foo: number; } */

type P = DeepExclude<[number | { foo: { bar: number } | number }], { bar: number }>;
/* type P = [number | {
    foo: number;
}] */
```

Yes, looks good.  There may well be edge cases that don't work the way you expect, so be careful and do lots of testing.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhFgKIA8DGAbArgEwgHgBUAaKAVQD4oBeAKCigKgmWAgDtsBnMqAfijYQAbhABOUAFx0GTFuy5QA9gCMAVhFTA+UAN7T6AbQDSUAJZsoAawghFAMwYBdCbHhI0WXIWOOSFaQC+kgwA3DQ0oJBQAPLUrggoGDj4OlB2iooubJgAtspiUAA+ulDKAIaiWbn54kEBJKnllQLVBQHkYQD0AFRQkdCxVCXpmS15YiFQQd2d4f1QAApxcAkeyXgG2ePixakjLo0VVdtTRWM1U74lTccX7V2980tDm607uvppGbcTNAGOUBmQA)

Comment: This approach appears to be turning the type of nested arrays to nested objects, any way to fix that?

Comment: You should probably provide a [mre] of what you're talking about, preferably also with a link to an IDE that demonstrates it, if you want me to look at something in particular.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following approach:

```
type ElementType<T extends unknown[]> = T extends (infer U)[] ? U : never;

type DeepExclude<T, U> = 
    U extends T 
        ? Exclude<T, U> 
        : T extends (infer E)[]
            ? (DeepExclude<E, U>[])
            : T extends Record<any, any> 
                ? { [P in keyof T] : DeepExclude<T[P], U> } 
                : T;
```

[Sample on Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhFgKIA8DGAbArgEwgHgBUAaKAVQD4oBeKAKCgbKgmWAgDtsBnKAuxgVAD8UFBhz5iZSvUEMAXL2asO3KAAoAluwBmEAE6iAlAG0AurLkCR6uAjFZceRCQrmjlqwqUs2nHgBKEKgA9vrYeACG7CAk0SAyXl4iAN5QJgAKUNpQANYQICE6vGZQinZIaI6SmWaulAC+-ElyigQA3LS0oJBQAMqRALZg6BAAjNSw8JXiTik6ISGK7JiDAEYGUAA+UClrkfrLqxv6DQ0kewdH6wYN5O1QAPSPu1ALS1ArN-oPDV090AGw1GACZJhUHBI8CYvidtrt3opLodPsdbvDYbc6rt9ijMad7k8Xup8fD5otricGqYzEA)

Comment: jcalz's version is better, that's short and beautiful! There is no need to handle arrays separately.